# Xamarin Forms | Android Dynamic File Access

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mime-types, file-access

I'm trying to open dynamic files with my Xamarin Forms Apps.
You can find below my code for the following process:

Essential Class using in my PCL project

```
 public class EssentialsService : IEssentialsService
    {
        public async Task OpenLinkBrowser(string URL)
        {
            await Browser.OpenAsync(URL);
        }
        public async Task<bool> CheckIfFileExists(string FileName)
        {
            return await DependencyService.Get<IDevice>().CheckFileExists("Download", FileName);
        }
        public async Task OpenExistingFile(string FileName)
        {
            await DependencyService.Get<IDevice>().ViewFile("Download", FileName);
        }
        public async Task OpenAttachmentLink(dynamic attachment)
        {
            StringToFreeSizeImageURLConverter stringToFreeSizeImageURLConverter = new StringToFreeSizeImageURLConverter();
            var fullLinkURL = stringToFreeSizeImageURLConverter.Convert(attachment.AttachementURL, null, null, null);
            string fileName = attachment.ID + "-" + attachment.Description;
            if (await CheckIfFileExists(fileName))
            {
                await OpenExistingFile(fileName);
                return;
            }
            if (!BaseApiService.IsConnceted())
            {
                //SHOW POPUP IF NO CONNECTION
                await BasePage.Resolve<INavigationService>().ShowETEPopup(LanguageClass.GetInstance().CHECK_YOUR_CONNECTION
                , LanguageClass.GetInstance().OK);
                return;
            }
            await OpenLinkBrowser(fullLinkURL as string);
        }
    }
```

Android specific code to open files

```
 public class DeviceAndroid : IDevice
    {
     public Task<bool> CheckFileExists(string folderName, string fileName)
            {
                string pathToDownloadsFolder = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
                Java.IO.File myDir = new Java.IO.File(pathToDownloadsFolder + "/" + folderName);
                if (!myDir.Exists()) return Task.FromResult(false);
                Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(myDir, fileName);
                if (file.Exists()) return Task.FromResult(true);
                else return Task.FromResult(false);
            }
      public Task<bool> ViewFile(string folderName, string fileName)
            {
                string pathToDownloadsFolder = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
                Java.IO.File myDir = new Java.IO.File(pathToDownloadsFolder + "/" + folderName);
                if (!myDir.Exists()) return Task.FromResult(false);
                Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(myDir, fileName);
                if (!file.Exists()) throw new Exception("Downloaded File Does Not Exist!");
                var packageName = Android.App.Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageName;
                Android.Net.Uri path = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Android.App.Application.Context, Android.App.Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageName + ".provider", file);
                string extension = Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file).ToString()); 
                string mimeType = Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, path);
                intent.SetDataAndType(path, mimeType);
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
                var chooserIntent = Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Choose App");
                chooserIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
                Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(chooserIntent);
                return Task.FromResult(true);
            }
}
```

AndroidMainfest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="2.0.3281" package="@appname" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.symbol.emdk.permission.EMDK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
  <!-- Request legacy Bluetooth + location permissions on older devices. -->
  <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />-->
  <!-- Request Bluetooth permissions on Android 12 and above (location not necessary). -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
    <application android:allowBackup="false" android:fullBackupContent="false" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <uses-library android:name="com.symbol.emdk" android:required="false" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="@appname.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
        <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="@appname.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
  <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

As you can see I'm using file provider solution in this link:
https://github.com/AlphaTechstudios/Xamarin-Forms/tree/0b7814d7ec47c2bbd05a8738a5ee2d3edd27f188/PdfFiles

The process is going as following:

- I'm opening the browser with the link of the file (for example excel
  file)
- The file will be downloaded successfully to the download folder in my device
- I check if the file exists in the download folder (also successfully completed)
- Then I try to open the file with specific mimetype according to the
  file type, an Intent appears

if there is multiple options to open the file and when I click on any of the options or if there is no options and I'm automatically directed to the only option that can open the file with, error is appearing that I'm unable to open the file. Noting that I'm able to open the file anytime from the download folder in my device and it does open correctly with no errors. Is anyone facing this problem?

Comment: Did this issue appear in any other projects?

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT I used to access the file after downloading it without using file provider, after upgrading target framework to 12, an error starting to appear when setting the mime type of the file, I found the file provider solution online I was able to set the mime type but error is occurring every time I try to open the file

Comment: So it may not the code problem. You metioned that you upgrade the target framework.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT Yes I did upgrade. The problem is both, code and target framework problem, since the old code is not working on the new target framework and the new code is not working also. I can't downgrade back to target framework 11 since I need everything in my app to be up to date, it is an app we are developing in my company. And as far as I know play story is not accepting applications below target framework 12

Comment: Are there any issue information or signals about the error?

Comment: No exception or visual errors, I will be checking the log cat by tomorrow and let you know if there is any errors appearing there